# Obtaining summary statistics from unique column combinations in R

Tags: r, summary

I have a file input.txt that I read in as a data frame, and I need to be able to get summary statistics from it as shown in "output".
Each ID in the file is unique, the Year and Status are not.

```
>input
ID  Year    Status
1   2002    OK
2   2002    OK
3   2003    NO
4   2003    OK
5   2007    OK
6   2007    NO
```

I've tried to use:

```
table(melt(input, id=c("ID"))
```

I'm still not getting what I would like. Below is the desired output I would like to get. 
I need to get the summary of individuals per year that had status OK and NO.

```
>output 
Year   OK   NO
2002    2   0
2003    1   1
2007    1   1
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
with(df, table(Year, Status))
#       Status
# Year   NO OK
#   2002  0  2
#   2003  1  1
#   2007  1  1

# or 
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Year ~ Status)

#   Year NO OK
# 1 2002  0  2
# 2 2003  1  1
# 3 2007  1  1
```